delay equation via mellin transform
Consider the delay differential equation:
$$
xf(x)−xf'(x)=2(f(x/2)−f(x)),\;\; x\ge0,
$$
subject to $f(0)=1$.
I am trying to solve it using the Mellin transform:
$$
M[f(x)](s)=\int_0^\infty f(x)\,x^{s}\,\dfrac{dx}{x}.
$$
Let $G(s)=M[f](s)$. Then $G(s+1)=M[xf(x)](s)$, $2^s G(s)=M[f(x/2)](s)$, and $-sG(s)=M[xf'(x)](s)$. Thus we have:
$$
G(s+1)+sG(s)=(2^{s+1}-2)G(s),
$$
or
$$
G(s+1)=G(s)(2^{s+1}-2-s).
$$
For integer $s$ the solution is of the form:
$$
G(s)=C\prod_{j=1}^{s-1} (2^{j+1}-2-j),
$$
for some $C$.
Can it be extended to non integer $s$? I sense there might be a connection here to something like the $q$-Pocchammer symbol.

I think that something is wrong: we have $G(s+1)=G(s)(2^{s+1}-2-s)$, so $G(1)=G(0)\cdot0=0$, $G(2)=0\cdot(2^{2}-2-1)=0$, ..., $G(n)=0$ for $\mathbb{Z}\ni n\geq1$, but your solution with the product only gives this solution for $C=0$. The problem is probably that you used this method described on Wikipedia to solve the equation, but that only works if the coefficient of $G(s)$ is never $0$ (since you would divide by $0$ otherwise), which is not the case here.
